# How can I have Objective-C++ and Swift and a framework in a single SPM project?

Tags: swift, opencv, raspberry-pi, swift-package-manager

I'm trying to use SwiftPM on a Raspberry Pi to write a command-line tool involving OpenCV. Is there any way for me to use Objective-C++, the Swift file, and the OpenCV framework all in the same project, and still be able to compile it with `swift build`?

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar on OSX but with C++ instead of ObjC++ (though my bridging-header is ObjC++) and I'm using GTK.  I'm also using Xcode for its debugging tools.  I can compile and run my app in Xcode, if I limit OpenCV references to my main.swift and in files/classes that are are co-located in the same folder, but I cannot access OpenCV from other classes defined in other `Sources/...` paths.  However, `swift build` is not working at all from the commandline.  I am using https://github.com/rhx/SwiftHelloGtkBuilder/blob/master/Package.swift as a reference project.